# All day event instance is inserted with wrong values for start and end values

Tags: android, calendar, timezone, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I add an All-day event into my generated calendar using `CalendarProvider` in my code. First I add an event in code. Then I add another event with google calendar into same calendar at the same day that is All-day to. Here is the result of querying the Event table for two events:

```
(allDay : 1)(dtstart : 1445817600000)(dtend : 1445904000000)(eventTimezone : UTC)(eventEndTimezone : null)(calendar_timezone : Asia/Tehran)(title :  me)
(allDay : 1)(dtstart : 1445817600000)(dtend : 1445904000000)(eventTimezone : UTC)(eventEndTimezone : null)(calendar_timezone : Asia/Tehran)(title : Google)
```

However this is the result of querying instance table:

```
(startDay : 2457322)(startMinute : 210)(begin : 1445817600000)(endDay : 2457323)(endMinute : 210) (end : 1445904000000)(title :  me)
(startDay : 2457322)(startMinute : 0)  (begin : 1445817600000)(endDay : 2457322)(endMinute : 1440)(end : 1445904000000)(title : Google)
```

My device timezone is GMT +3:30. According to [google documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html), I have set `UTC` for event timezone. But it seems that the calendar provider doesn't consider it and adds 210 = +3.5 * 60 minute to instance start and end. This causes that google calendar shows my event in two days. So what is the problem? Should I set another column for correct behavior?

**NOTE:** When I set device timezone to `UTC`, instance table save correct values (0 for start minute and 1440 for end minute).